# Usage of chinese characters in java application

Tags: java

i am trying to display unicode characters(Chinese) in my application.The jsp part is working fine and has no issues by setting the charset to UTF-8.But in the Java code , Unicode characters are not displayed.I tried by setting the request to utf-8

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Finally i will be getting the same and insert in to the table.The database is already configured for unicode support.

what am i doing wrong.Kindly advice on the solution or is there a better way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Is your request `POST` or `GET`?

Comment: Do you have Asian fonts installed?

Comment: please provide info ! requested above

Comment: Yes i have the asian fonts installed.i am trying to post the values from my JSP Page to the servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement Filter in your application for character encoding:

```
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig)
            throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        servletRequest.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        servletResponse.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

And if you are using tomcat, make sure that your connector element has URIEncoding attribute which value is UTF-8.

```
<Connector port="8080" 
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Also make sure that you specifying this in every JSP page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Hope this helps.